# Missing xxx.dll when performing built executives in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dynamic-linking

The system warned that missing `opencv_core331.dll`[image]

However, I have added the path of directory that include `opencv_core331.dll` to the environment variables of Windows:

[image][image]

Who can help?

Comment: Can you try adding the directory to ( Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories )  Note: I am sorry, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I ensure I have added path of the directory  that include all related libraries to Libaray Directories of Visual Studio, or the linker will report errors without above setting.

Comment: I found some other SO Q/As to similar topics googling "stackoverflow C++ VS deploy".

Comment: To deal with dependencies located in a different place than the working directory while debugging, I just adjust the debugging environment `PATH` variable. Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Environment, where i have something like `PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a run-time issue, the libraries path has nothing to do with it. You need to either edit the global PATH variable  or the executable directories in the project properties. I would personally recommend the global PATH variable because that way your program will run outside of VS as well as from it.

To do so, in the start menu search box type "environment" and select the ""Edit system environment variables" if you want to make the change for all accounts.environment variables for your account" or (

Comment: Another work-around: Copy all dependent DLLs (except Windows/VS runtime DLLs) into the directory where the executable is located. Hence, no changes to `PATH` are necessary. This also simplifies release/deploy as everything necessary is located in one directory for application "packing and delivery".

Comment: I have done that just like what you mean, path of directory that includes all related dynamic linking libraries has been added to the system environment variables as showed in the second picture